# div align direita

Tags: html, css

Estou tentando alinhar essa div no quanto Direito da tela e ela fica só no esquerdo

```
    <div class="tres">
<iframe data-aa='861335' src='#' scrolling='no' style='width:120px; height:60px; border:0px; padding:0;overflow:hidden' allowtransparency='true'></iframe>
</div>
```

css usado

```
div.tres {
 position: absolute;
 justify-content: center;
 align-items: center;
 background-color:  gray;
 border: 2px solid; /* As 4 bordas sólidas com 25px de espessura */
 border-color: gray  gray gray  gray; /* cores: topo, direita, inferior, esquerda */
 }
```

```css
div.tres {
 position: absolute;
 justify-content: center;
 align-items: center;
 background-color:  gray;
 border: 2px solid; /* As 4 bordas sólidas com 25px de espessura */
 border-color: gray  gray gray  gray; /* cores: topo, direita, inferior, esquerda */
 }
```

```html
<div class="tres">
<iframe data-aa='861335' src='#' scrolling='no' style='width:120px; height:60px; border:0px; padding:0;overflow:hidden' allowtransparency='true'></iframe>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
div.tres {
 float: right;
 justify-content: center;
 align-items: center;
 background-color:  gray;
 border: 2px solid;
 border-color: gray  gray gray  gray; 
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Basta adicionar um `right : 0`, caso queira permanecer com o comportamento absoluto...

```css
div.tres {
 position: absolute;
 right: 0;
 justify-content: center;
 align-items: center;
 background-color:  gray;
 border: 2px solid; /* As 4 bordas sólidas com 25px de espessura */
 border-color: gray  gray gray  gray; /* cores: topo, direita, inferior, esquerda */
 }
```

```html
<div class="tres">
<iframe data-aa='861335' src='#' scrolling='no' style='width:120px; height:60px; border:0px; padding:0;overflow:hidden' allowtransparency='true'></iframe>
</div>
```